# How can I display the insert link C-c C-l dialog when starting to capture data in Org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have this capture entry:

```
("b" "Bookmark" entry (file+headline "~/orgfiles/bookmarks.org" "Temp")
 "* %?\n" :empty-line 1)
```

The `bookmarks.org` contains a heading called `temp` where I save all kind of temporary link that needs to be reviewed later.

This is how the file looks:

```
* Emacs
  - Emacs related bookmark 1
  - Emacs related bookmark 2
* Linux
  - Linux related bookmark 1
* Web Development
  - Web development related bookmarks
  - ...
* Temp
  - Captured links go here
```

I don't see any reason to creare a separate file for storing these capture links.

How can I make my capture template work in the way that when I enter `org-capture` and select `[b]` for bookmark in that moment to prompt for the link like I was pressing C-c C-l (`org-insert-link`)? Instead of entering the link manually by typing.